# находится ли изображение в зоне видимости

Tags: javascript, jquery

здравствуйте, как можно с помощью jquery  при скроллинге определять если изображение попало в поле видимости, то show() его, если вышло из поля видимости то hide()?

Comment: [Basic Visibility Detection](http://opensource.teamdf.com/visible/examples/demo-basic.html) Вот только никак не могу понять, зачем скрывать то, что и так не видимо?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, чтобы оно с сервера не грузилось.

Comment: Это не поможет.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, ну я думаю в данном случае, это общий вопрос о динамичности объектов на странице, чтобы при прокрутке страницы всё двигалось, как нынче модно :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задаёте следующую функцию, принимающую селектор в качестве первого аргумента и логическое значение для выбора видимых (true) или невидимых (false) элементов:

```
function inWindow(s, v) {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var currentEls = $(s);
  var resultVis = [];
  var resultInv = [];
  currentEls.each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    var offset = el.offset();
    if (scrollTop <= offset.top && (el.height() + offset.top) < (scrollTop + windowHeight))
      resultVis.push(this);
    else resultInv.push(this);
  });
  if (v) return $(resultVis);
  else return $(resultInv);
}
```

Затем, в нужный момент вызываете, например, при скроллинге:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var imagesVisible = inWindow("img.myimage", true);
  var imagesInvisible = inWindow("img.myimage", false);
  imagesVisible.fadeIn();
  imagesInvisible.fadeOut();
});
```